# Why is my Facebook Messenger app not being approved?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My company has been developing a Facebook Messenger app that will send reservation reminders to hotel guests before their check in date.  I have submitted the app to use the "pages_messaging_subscriptions", but have had my submission be denied.

I am confused about how I am supposed to move forward from here.  The response from the process was "Your Messenger experience does not fall into the productivity use case that you submitted for.".   One of the use cases for a productivity app is sending reminders.  This is exactly what my companies app will be doing.

How do I move forward from here?  Has anyone had a similar experience?  There does not seem to be any way to follow up with the reviewer to get further feedback.

Comment: What kind of reminders are you trying to send, what about? Most rejections happen because people do not interpret the three given categories narrowly enough. Facebook wants to see a real benefit to the end user. If that is not given, and they suspect that your reminders are just thinly veiled advertising, they reject it.

Comment: @CBroe Reminders about check in time and reminder about time of appointments at the hotel such as a spa appointment.

Comment: Ok, that doesn’t seem that far of as some things I’ve read (people trying to send daily horoscopes, etc.), and should fit into the Productivity category: _“tasks such as managing calendar events, receiving reminders”_ So you can only submit again and try to reason with them why your bot falls into this category. I don’t know if it is possible to includes screenshots and/or examples in messenger bot review notes?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems your use case of "sending reminders" falls into Facebook's Bot "Productivity" category, my suggestion would be to re-submit the application again.

If Facebook sent some sort of response regarding exactly *why* your application was rejected, look at that. If there isn't a response from Facebook regarding why it was rejected (other than some generic "because we said so"), after re-submitting your application - assuming it gets denied again - I would try to get into contact with Facebook to see the exact reason it was rejected, and work with them on a solution that allows you to get your application/bot published.

Unfortunately, as I don't work for Facebook, I can't give you a 100% accurate answer, but instead what I think would be the best course of action in this situation.